# Want to bypass sink valve tap but what is the connector called?

Tags: plumbing, repair, installation

I want to remove the valve of my sink so that the water flows directly into the inlet of the sink tap instead of going through an additional tap. I'm attaching the screenshot for reference purpose (sorry, I couldn't find a better image on the net)[image]

The problem is I don't know the technical name of the connector. For the record, this is for an Indian home, so maybe the size standards and naming convention may vary here.

Comment: Don't do it. That valve is likely there to allow you to turn off the water if you ever have to repair/replace the sink faucet (tap).    If you remove it, you'll have to shut the water off somewhere else (possibly the whole house) to repair/replace this sink faucet (tap).

Comment: I'm aware of that. The thing is there's already another valve at the start of the pipe that is connecting to this valve tap. So I can just turn that one off.

Comment: You're probably the only person who knows where that 'other valve' is. In case of some unforeseen event, the normal place for anyone to look for the shutoff valve would be right under the sink... Imo replacing this valve with a simple elbow is a bad idea.

Comment: @brhans Not a biggie really. The reason I know where the other valve is because it's coming from a overhead tank inside my bathroom. So the entire pipeline is visible to me.

Comment: WHY, do you want to remove the shut off valve?

Comment: @Alaskaman I don't want too many stop points in between the pipelines (there already is a valve at the other end that  I can use in case of a repair). The water pressure is too low in the tap and yes, I've checked there is no clogging of any sort.